# php how to do include right way

Tags: php, path, include

Hello i'm running WAMP (32 Bit) server

i exec C:\wamp\www\1\index.php using browser with this address http://localhost:8080/1/

index.php has the follow code

```
require_once 'libraries/database/database.php';
```

database.php has the follow code

```
require_once '../misc/traits/singleton.php';
```

singleton.php is located in this location

```
C:\wamp\www\1\libraries\misc\traits\singleton.php
```

database.php is located in this location

```
C:\wamp\www\1\libraries\database\database.php
```

and there is error(s):

( ! ) Warning: require_once(../misc/traits/singleton.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\1\libraries\database\database.php on line 3

( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../misc/traits/singleton.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\1\libraries\database\database.php on line 3

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths stem from the php file that was originally executed, unless you change the path using chdir.

So use `'libraries/misc/traits/singleton.php'`

If you want to do relative includes, use `__DIR__`, which is the directory of the CURRENT file.

e.g.

`__DIR__ . '/../misc/traits/singleton.php'`

Comment: Best practice would be using autoloading. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php